# Amazon Elastic MapReduce - Format or Examples for python map and reduce code

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce

Maybe it is the same has Hadoop but I just couldn't find what is the format or example of writing the map and reduce python code beside map example here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/GettingStartedGuide/

but I couldn't find reduce code example,

is it the same as Hadoop?
and what is the format and are there any examples anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EMR streaming is no different to general Hadoop streaming.

Here's an example of a python reducer
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/#reduce-reducer-py